# Should I be worried with this Python error message after installing Seaborn?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, seaborn, tqdm

I am using `Python 3.6.3` and it was installed using `Anaconda`.

I have run the following command at the Command Prompt to install Seaborn.

I got the following error message at the end of the installation process: `CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist.`

I am also including below the whole installation messages:

```
C:\>conda install -c anaconda seaborn
Fetching package metadata ...............
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    blas:                   1.0-mkl               anaconda
    conda-package-handling: 1.6.1-py36h62dcd97_0  anaconda
    tqdm:                   4.48.2-py_0           anaconda

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    anaconda:               5.0.1-py36h8316230_2           --> custom-py36h363777c_0  anaconda
    conda:                  4.3.30-py36h7e176b0_0          --> 4.8.4-py36_0           anaconda
    matplotlib:             2.1.0-py36h11b4b9c_0           --> 2.1.2-py36h016c42a_0   anaconda
    menuinst:               1.4.10-py36h42196fb_0          --> 1.4.16-py36he774522_1  anaconda
    mkl:                    2018.0.0-h36b65af_4            --> 2018.0.3-1             anaconda
    openssl:                1.0.2l-vc14hcac20b0_2          --> 1.0.2t-vc14h62dcd97_0  anaconda [vc14]
    pandas:                 0.20.3-py36hce827b7_2          --> 0.25.3-py36ha925a31_0  anaconda
    pycosat:                0.6.2-py36hf17546d_1           --> 0.6.3-py36he774522_0   anaconda
    scipy:                  0.19.1-py36h7565378_3          --> 1.1.0-py36hc28095f_0   anaconda
    seaborn:                0.8.0-py36h62cb67c_0           --> 0.10.1-py_0            anaconda
    vc:                     14-h2379b0c_2                  --> 14.1-h0510ff6_4        anaconda
    vs2015_runtime:         14.0.25123-hd4c4e62_2          --> 14.16.27012-hf0eaf9b_3 anaconda

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

    bzip2:                  1.0.6-vc14hdec8e7a_1           --> 1.0.6-vc14hdec8e7a_1   anaconda [vc14]
    conda-env:              2.6.0-h36134e3_1               --> 2.6.0-1                anaconda
    curl:                   7.55.1-vc14hdaba4a4_3          --> 7.55.1-vc14hdaba4a4_3  anaconda [vc14]
    freetype:               2.8-vc14h17c9bdf_0             --> 2.8-vc14h17c9bdf_0     anaconda [vc14]
    hdf5:                   1.10.1-vc14hb361328_0          --> 1.10.1-vc14hb361328_0  anaconda [vc14]
    icu:                    58.2-vc14hc45fdbb_0            --> 58.2-vc14hc45fdbb_0    anaconda [vc14]
    jpeg:                   9b-vc14h4d7706e_1              --> 9b-vc14h4d7706e_1      anaconda [vc14]
    libiconv:               1.15-vc14h29686d3_5            --> 1.15-vc14h29686d3_5    anaconda [vc14]
    libpng:                 1.6.32-vc14h5163883_3          --> 1.6.32-vc14h5163883_3  anaconda [vc14]
    libssh2:                1.8.0-vc14hcf584a9_2           --> 1.8.0-vc14hcf584a9_2   anaconda [vc14]
    libtiff:                4.0.8-vc14h04e2a1e_10          --> 4.0.8-vc14h04e2a1e_10  anaconda [vc14]
    libxml2:                2.9.4-vc14h8fd0f11_5           --> 2.9.4-vc14h8fd0f11_5   anaconda [vc14]
    libxslt:                1.1.29-vc14hf85b8d4_5          --> 1.1.29-vc14hf85b8d4_5  anaconda [vc14]
    lzo:                    2.10-vc14h0a64fa6_1            --> 2.10-vc14h0a64fa6_1    anaconda [vc14]
    qt:                     5.6.2-vc14h6f8c307_12          --> 5.6.2-vc14h6f8c307_12  anaconda [vc14]
    sqlite:                 3.20.1-vc14h7ce8c62_1          --> 3.20.1-vc14h7ce8c62_1  anaconda [vc14]
    tk:                     8.6.7-vc14hb68737d_1           --> 8.6.7-vc14hb68737d_1   anaconda [vc14]
    yaml:                   0.1.7-vc14hb31d195_1           --> 0.1.7-vc14h4cb57cf_1   anaconda [vc14]
    zlib:                   1.2.11-vc14h1cdd9ab_1          --> 1.2.11-vc14h1cdd9ab_1  anaconda [vc14]

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

menuinst-1.4.1 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00 840.32 kB/s
blas-1.0-mkl.t 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   2.07 MB/s
conda-env-2.6. 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   1.41 MB/s
vs2015_runtime 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   8.42 MB/s
mkl-2018.0.3-1 100% |###############################| Time: 0:01:27   2.13 MB/s
vc-14.1-h0510f 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   3.10 MB/s
bzip2-1.0.6-vc 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   6.19 MB/s
icu-58.2-vc14h 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:18   1.25 MB/s
jpeg-9b-vc14h4 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   1.03 MB/s
libiconv-1.15- 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00 911.44 kB/s
libssh2-1.8.0- 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   2.54 MB/s
lzo-2.10-vc14h 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00 520.90 kB/s
openssl-1.0.2t 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:03   1.90 MB/s
sqlite-3.20.1- 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   1.42 MB/s
tk-8.6.7-vc14h 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:01   2.75 MB/s
yaml-0.1.7-vc1 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   1.16 MB/s
zlib-1.2.11-vc 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   2.04 MB/s
anaconda-custo 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   3.05 MB/s
curl-7.55.1-vc 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   2.06 MB/s
hdf5-1.10.1-vc 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:18   1.85 MB/s
libpng-1.6.32- 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   1.75 MB/s
libtiff-4.0.8- 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   3.07 MB/s
libxml2-2.9.4- 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   3.58 MB/s
pycosat-0.6.3- 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   9.47 MB/s
tqdm-4.48.2-py 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00 965.65 kB/s
conda-package- 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   8.13 MB/s
freetype-2.8-v 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   8.77 MB/s
libxslt-1.1.29 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   3.63 MB/s
qt-5.6.2-vc14h 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:26   2.24 MB/s
scipy-1.1.0-py 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:05   2.59 MB/s
pandas-0.25.3- 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:04   2.58 MB/s
matplotlib-2.1 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:02   2.93 MB/s
seaborn-0.10.1 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   1.03 MB/s
conda-4.8.4-py 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   4.38 MB/s
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(337): An error occurred while installing package 'anaconda::tqdm-4.48.2-py_0'.
CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
Running `conda clean --packages` may resolve your problem.
Attempting to roll back.
    
CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
Running `conda clean --packages` may resolve your problem.
```

I haven't yet run `conda clean --packages` (as suggested above) for fear I may mess things up.

When I run `pip show seaborn`, it gives me `Seaborn version 0.8` (as at now, Seaborn is version 0.11.0).

Did the installation fail? What should be the next steps? And how do I get `Seaborn 0.11.0`?

Comment: 1. this is not a problem, just run `conda clean --packages` as suggested to clean the packages cache.
2.  to be sure, install tqdm first by running `conda install tqdm`

Answer (score 0):

1. this is not a problem, just run `conda clean --packages` as suggested to clean the packages cache.
2. to be sure, install tqdm first by running `conda install tqdm`
3. run `conda install seaborn` again

Comment: Thanks. But I was expecting that Seaborn 0.11.0 would have been installed.

Comment: correct. so after 1. and 2. repeat `conda install seaborn`